# getting random gaps in my print statements python

Tags: python

I am trying to print a statement in python and getting gaps and missing letters, this only happens when I use "". I was trying to enter the path.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rezQh.png)

check the image

I am using vs code, anaconda, Jupiter notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\t` in your string is an escape character which translates to a tab. In order to ignore the escape characters you can use raw strings by placing an `r` before the string. Examples:

```
print("aa\tbb")
aa  bb
```

With raw strings:

```
print(r"aa\tbb")
aa\tbb
```

Answer (score 1):

Happening because in `dog\train`, `\t` is being considered as Tab escape character.
to fix it, simply put another `\` in front of 't' `\\t`.